# Samantha age 40, buys a 20-year certain-and-life annuity due with a single premium. Find the reserve 5 years after issue.

Tags: actuarial-science

> Samantha age 40, buys a 20-year certain-and-life annuity due with a
>   single premium. The annuity makes annual payments of $2,000$. If $i = 6\%$
>   and you are given the following table, find the reserve 5 years after
>   issue. (hint: the benefit is an annuity)
>
> $l_{40} = 39,143.64$
>
> $l_{45} = 23,582.45$
>
> $l_{60} = 400.49$
>
> $\ddot{a}_{40} = 5.90503$
>
> $\ddot{a}_{45} = 4.69803$
>
> $\ddot{a}_{60} = 2.12522$

So far I have: (sorry, some of the notation is difficult to create)

Premium (per 1 dollar) = $\dfrac{A_{40}}{\ddot{a}_{40:\overline{10}|}} = \dfrac{1 - d\ddot{a}_{40}}{\ddot{a}_{40:\overline{10}|}} = \dfrac{1 - (0.06/1.06)(5.90503)}{ ? }$

** I can't seem to figure out what $\ddot{a}_{40:\overline{10}|}$ is?

Furthermore, I know how to finally finish off the question as:

$2000 {}_5 ^{20}$$V_{40}= (2000)(1 - d\ddot{a}_{45}) - (2000)(\text{Premium})(\ddot{a}_{45:\overline{5}|})$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actuarial present value of the benefits is 
$$2000\ddot{a}_{\overline{40:\overline{20}|}} = 2000(\ddot{a}_{\overline{20}|}+{}_{20|}\ddot{a}_{40}) = 2000(\ddot{a}_{\overline{20}|}+\ddot{a}_{60}\cdot {}_{20}E_{40})$$
(do you see why?) and assuming the equivalence principle, note that you have a **single** premium, so letting $P$ be the single premium,
$$P = 2000(\ddot{a}_{\overline{20}|}+\ddot{a}_{60}\cdot {}_{20}E_{40})\text{.}$$
I'm assuming you know how to compute these. You should know $\ddot{a}_{\overline{20}|}$ from FM.

The formula you have for the premium is false, since 1) we're not working with a whole-life insurance as the benefit, but rather, an annuity; 2) we only have ONE premium (so $\ddot{a}_{40:\overline{10}|}$ is unnecessary).

The reserve (I like using the simple notation ${}_{5}V$ for this) is 
$${}_{5}V = 2000\ddot{a}_{\overline{15}|}+{}_{15|}\ddot{a}_{45}=2000\ddot{a}_{\overline{15}|}+\ddot{a}_{60}\cdot {}_{15}E_{45}\text{.}$$
Note here that NO PREMIUM is included. (Why?)

Comment: is it because there is only one single premium? Also, I don't have what a¨15  is in the last equation

Comment: @queence There is no premium after time 5. Note that under the prospective method for reserves, we're looking at FUTURE premiums which will be subtracted. The $\ddot{a}_{15}$ is a typo. (See edit.)

Comment: yes right, that makes sense. alright thanks a lot!